# Ubuntu 14.04 no ethernet connection, network manager detects only wireless networks

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

Installation from Live CD of Ubuntu 14.04 on ASUS-based desktop (motherboard M3A-79T Deluxe with 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller by Marvell) highlighted 'no internet connection' issue. So I plugged USB WiFi dongle which was immediately detected by network manager so installation has downloaded all updates via WiFi.
Upon restart updated network manager failed to detect connection on my eth0 again. Literally I was able to create and store new connection manually but never had a chance to get connected with it.
Running following commands in console gave me below results:

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0     Link encap: Ethernet    HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
..........
Interrupt: 18

$ sudo lshw -c network
*-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
.......
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:1
.......
```

When I tried

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

or

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

the feedback was `Cannot assign requested address`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Upon finishing my quest on number of similar topics here is the solution that worked in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked in my case is as follows. As MAC-address of my ethernet card is set to 00:00:00:00:00:00 by manufacturer, I forcibly set it to non-zero unique value (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) which is white-listed in router. To prevent conflicts between eth0 with forcibly set MAC-address and other network clients I assigned static IP-address (192.168.1.10 in my case) for eth0. In order to prevent any foreseen issues with DNS I've forcibly set it to Google servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). To make all assignments permanent I've changed `/etc/network/interfaces` as below:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    hwaddress ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Then in console I've entered following commands:

```
$ sudo ifdown eth0
```

this is to shut down old settings of eth0

```
$ sudo stop network-manager

$ echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.overrride
```

this is to bypass network manager settings

```
$ sudo ifup eth0
```

this is to bring eth0 up with new settings

After reboot network manager applet still has '?'-mark on it but network via eth0 works as it should .